# pl to exe using Par::Packer - How to use

Tags: perl, exe

I have a perl script which needs to be converted to a exe file. I saw that Par packer will help to achieve this. But I have no idea on how to install this Par packer and do the conversion. Can someone please guide me ? Any tutorial videos will help a lot.

here is the code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use warnings;
 use strict;


for my $file (glob '*.mobi *.prc *.epub') {
my ($ext) = $file =~ /\.(.*)/;
if ($ext =~ /mobi|prc/i) {
    my $status = system qw{ kindletool.exe strip_source }, $file;
    warn "Failure $status: $file" if $status;

} elsif (lc $ext eq 'epub') {
    (my $newname = $file) =~ s/\.epub$/.zip/;
    rename $file, $newname or warn "Failure $!: $file";
}
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? What is error you are getting?

Comment: http://strawberryperl.com/download/5.16.3.1/strawberry-perl-5.16.3.1-32bit.msi => `cpanm pp` (newer strawberry has problem installing pp)

Comment: there seems to be no error with my code..I dont know how to create a exe using par packer..I need help on how to install and compile a exe using this.

Comment: The code is irrelevant, it looks like OP is just asking for a general guide on how to install Par Packer. What have you tried? Do you have previous experience installing CPAN modules? What platform are you on?

Comment: How about... `cpanm PAR::Packer`?

Comment: I downloaded PAR-Packer-1.026 and have it in my local drive. I need to know how to install this and convert pl to exe..

Comment: @mohad either read the advice above `cpan pp` or `cpanm pp` or actually read the documentation for the tool you have chosen to use. This explains how to install.

Comment: I did open cmd and typed cpan pp...and it ran a long list...and everything was ok..What is the next step to do ? The read me page doesn't help much on what to open or how to type it

Comment: The documentation explains clearly everything you've been told up to this step, including installation, and how to use the tool. It's not magic, you have to read and understand it

Answer (score 1):

```
pp -x -o outputexename yourscriptname.pl
```

This will generate `outputexename.exe`, specified by `-o`. The `-x` means that perl will run your code prior to packing to include any additional runtime dependancies (modules etc). See also [PAR::FAQ](https://metacpan.org/pod/PAR::FAQ)

**Edit**

To install the module, from the command prompt run:

```
cpan pp
```

or if you have cpanm installed

```
cpanm pp
```

The bare minimum you should do for any tool you decide to use is read the documentation: https://metacpan.org/source/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.026/README

Comment: Hi there. I'm new to coding and stuff..esp installing packages or modules. I have no idea. So I did open cmd and typed cpan pp...and it ran a long list...and everything was ok..What is the next step to do ?

Comment: if everything installed ok (`pp -V` will show you the version output) simply read and follow the steps I described in my answer above, which already tell you how to use pp to package your program

Comment: I opened cmd and type the command  the following and got an error msg :C:\Users\mohad>pp -x -o test testscript.pl
'pp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: C:\Users\mohad> cpan -D pp
CPAN: Term::ANSIColor loaded ok (v4.03)
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.49_01)
Reading 'C:\Perl64\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 10 Sep 2015 05:17:02 GMT
pp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at C:/Perl64/lib/App/C
pan.pm line 1158.
        (no description)
        R/RS/RSCHUPP/PAR-Packer-1.026.tar.gz
        Installed:
        CPAN:      0.992  Not up to date
        Roderich Schupp (RSCHUPP)
        rschupp@cpan.org

Comment: You have not installed the module. See comments above.

Comment: What am I doing wrong here ? :( I did try the "cpan pp" command in cmd

Comment: You said "and everything was ok" which does not tie up to the fact the module is not installed, as tested above. You need to learn basics here, programing, problem solving. Basically doing your job.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with installing packages..pls bear with me

Comment: You have to read the output of the commands you run. Clearly something did not complete as required